# How to return multiple values from a method?

Tags: c#, return

From the following code, I want `y` to return multiple values, but the program returns only the last one.

```cs
public int runDraw()
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= numberofDraws; j++)
    {
        ...
        if (even_count > odd_count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result of {0} draw is Even.", j);
            y = 1;
        }
        else if (even_count < odd_count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result of {0} draw is Odd.", j);
            y = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result of {0} draw is Draw.", j);
            y = 3;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: What type of object do you want the method to return?

Comment: `y` can only hold a single value at a time.  The fact that you **re**set it in a loop doesnt change that and it only `return`s after the entire loop has run

Comment: You can use the iterator method.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to return an enumeration of int, as a single int cannot represent multiple values directly. Here's an example using `yield return` which will only bother continuing to the next value if you ever ask for it.

```
    public IEnumerable<int> runDraw()
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= numberofDraws; j++)
        {
        ...
            if (even_count > odd_count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result of {0} draw is Even.", j);
                yield return 1;
            }
            else if (even_count < odd_count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result of {0} draw is Odd.", j);
                yield return 2;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result of {0} draw is Draw.", j);
                yield return 3;
            }
        }
        yield return y;
        // What you do here really depends on your unshared logic
        // You might return 0 or throw an exception if this is invalid
    }
```

You can then access the values iteratively, for example with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (int j in runDraw())
{
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this via array or collection.

1. Using array

   ```
    int[] result = new int[numberofDraws];
    result[j] = your result (1,2,3 based on condition)
    return result;
   ```
2. Using List

   ```
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    result.Add(1);
    return result;
   ```

**Note:**  Change the return type as per usage in case you are going with an array use `int[]`, if you are going with list use `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ****out**** parameters or ****tuples**** for returning multiple values from any function, check for them.